# "Belongs in another area" close-vote doesn't let me suggest area?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, migration

Whether via browser or app, when I try to select this reason the only choice offered is the local Meta. If that's deliberate, the language inviting us to choose, and indeed that whole step, are misleading/redundant. If it isn't, could we get this fixed someday?

Comment: I can't find the said "belong in another site" flag anymore.  It used to exist before...

Comment: @m0sa the "could we get this fixed someday?" part makes this kind of feature request. Maybe better put back that tag and add [tag:status-declined]? Know it's nitpicking, but I just like to keep things organized. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard  the "could we get this fixed someday?" part kind of excludes [tag:feature-request]...

Comment: @m0sa fair enough. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't intend to assert it either as bug or missing feature, just as issue.  Feel free to edit/rephrase to make it more suitable for the queues.

Answer (score 9):

Each site has its own list, which may be as small as its per-site meta. This is by design. You can't move to an arbitrary site, only to those the site admins have decided are typical targets.

However if you are sure it belongs somewhere that is not on the list, use an Other flag and explain to the moderator where you think it should be migrated to.

Comment: Ok, so I should pester the area heads if a particular kind of referral is happening frequently... Good enough. The UI does not make this at all clear; room for improvement there.

Comment: Not only do the referrals need to happen frequently, they need to be of a kind that the target site would accept. We don't encourage the migration of nonsense.